# Android Programming - Not getting list of items under a folder on a SD card

Tags: android

I have developed a android application which plays music on my phone.
I have created the following directory structure on my phone.

data

- Music

  - Engish

    - Song 1
    - Song 2
  - Jazz

    - Song 1
    - Song 2

### Code Snippet

1. To get the list of Music categories (returns the folder names)

---

```
filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile().getPath() + "/data/Music/");
String[] directories = filepath.list(new FilenameFilter()
```

The list of categories gets populated on the phone

- English
- Jazz

When the user selects a category (eg: English), the list of songs get populated for that category.

2. To get the list of songs under a Category

---

```
File filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsoluteFile().getPath() + "/data/Music/");
folder = filepath.toString() + "/" + categoryName;
```

**folder value = /storage/emulated/0/data/Music/English**

```
folder = folder + "/%";
**folder value = /storage/emulated/0/data/Music/English/%**
String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { folder };
String[] col = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
musiccursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                                 MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, col, where,
                                 whereArgs,
                                 "UPPER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
musiclist = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.MusicList);
            musiclist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.song_list_item, musiccursor));
            musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
```

The above code works on my phone.

3. Now I want to move the songs to a SD (Storage) Card on my phone.

---

For that I had to create the following directory structure
On the card, there is already a folder Android/data.
Within that I had to create a folder called com.android.gmp/files/data (gmp is my package name).
So the directory struture is:
Android

- data

  - com.android.gmp

    - files

      - data

        - Music

          - Engish

            - Song 1
            - Song 2
          - Jazz

            - Song 1
            - Song 2

4. The code to get the folders from the card

---

```
File[] storages = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(getActivity(), null);

if (storages.length > 1 && storages[0] != null && storages[1] != null) {

File file = storages[1];
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
filepath = new File(path + "/data/Music/");
String[] directories = filepath.list(new FilenameFilter();

}
```

**filepath value = /storage/3862-3539/Android/data/com.android.gmp/files/data/Music**

The list of categories gets populated on the phone

- English
- Jazz

5. To get the songs under the category (**No songs are returned - this is the issue**)

---

```
folder = filepath.toString() + "/" + categoryName;
```

**folder value = /storage/3862-3539/Android/data/com.android.gmp/files/data/Music/English/%**

Same code as above

```
String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { folder };
String[] col = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
musiccursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                                 MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, col, where,
                                 whereArgs,
                                 "UPPER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
musiclist = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.MusicList);
            musiclist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.song_list_item, musiccursor));
            musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
```

This query does not work, does not get the songs under the folder - if anyone can let me know where the issue is.
There are lots of other classes in the application but this issue is specifically getting files under a folder on a SD card

Comment: `filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile().getPath() + "/data/Music/");` Change to: `filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "data/Music");` The other ones too.

Comment: `Now I want to move the songs to a SD (Storage) Card on my phone.` Pretty unclear what you want. They are on external storage. What do you mean with SD?

Comment: `. Within that I had to create a folder called com.android.gmp/files/` Pretty strange. Not possible on Android 11+. Moreover you should have called getExternalFilesDir(null) and all was created for you. And di not call that SD. Its app specific storage on external storage.

Comment: `filepath = new File(path + "/data/Music/")` That shoud be `filepath = new File(file, "data/Music")` And indeed that is removable micro sd card.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. It looks as if you wanna copy/move your data folder on external storage to app specific storage on micro sd card. If so then just use old java io copy code to copy a directory recursive.

Comment: From the above comments, looks like I have added too much description. Here is the summary. I have a android  phone which has a removeable card. I have a folder on the card. Folder name=data/com.android.gmp/files/data/Music. Inside Music folder, I have 2 folders named English and Jazz. Under English, I have 2 files. Thru android programming 1. I want to get the list of folders 2. When user clicks on English, I want to retrieve the 2 files in that folder.

Comment: We have no idea which app the user is using where he sees folders and can click on them.

Comment: You talked and talked about folder structue and moving to sd but the only thing you had to say was: I have a folder  `/storage/3862-3539/Android/data/com.android.gmp/files/data/Music/English` And i am unable to list the files in that folder. The rest is only confusing.

Comment: blackapps, now that issue is clear, do you have any suggestion how to list the files in the folder?

Comment: You know how to list() so what is the problem ? Or question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for my issue.
I had to get a list of songs from a external storage (SD card)and populate a ListView using a cursor.
I already have code which was populating the songs from internal storage so did not want to make too many changes.
Below is the code snippet

Step 1. Create a new Content Provider (SongContentProvider inherited from ContentProvider)

```
   `public class SongContentProvider extends ContentProvider
   
 Overwrite the query method
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {
    
    //selection contains folder path (in my case = /storage/3862-3539/Android/data/com.android.gmp/files/data/Music/English
    String[] matrixColumns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
         MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
         MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
         MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
    MatrixCursor songListCursor = new MatrixCursor(matrixColumns);
    File directory = null;
    File[] fileList = null;
    directory = new File(selection);
    fileList = directory.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(fileList);
            
    Object[] mRow = new Object[4];
    for(int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++){
        mRow[0] = i;
        mRow[1] = fileList[i];
        mRow[2] = fileList[i].getName();
        mRow[3] = "";
        songListCursor.addRow(mRow);
    }
    return songListCursor;
}
```

`
Step 2. Call query from PlaySongFragment.java

```
private final Uri songContentProvider =
        Uri.parse("content://com.android.gmp.songs/songs");  
Cursor musiccursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(songContentProvider, null, folderPath, null, null);
musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.song_list_item, musiccursor));
```

Step 3. Add content provider to the manifest.xml

```
<provider
       android:authorities="com.android.gmp.songs"
       android:name=".SongContentProvider">
    </provider>
```